# Highcharts 3d bar chart data labels position is wrong

Tags: highcharts

I need to show bar chart with data labels.
When it is 2d, all is fine.
But when I show it as 3d bar the data labels position get wrong.
The code below:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        margin: 75,
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 35,
            beta: 15,
            depth: 110
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            depth: 40,
            stacking: true,
            grouping: false,
            groupZPadding: 10,
            dataLabels:{enabled:true}
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        stack: 0
    }, {
        data: [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2],
        stack: 0
    }, {
        data: [7, 9, 8, 7, 5, 8],
        stack: 1
    }]
});
```

});

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4dccq/277/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle? In default demo data labels are looking OK - http://jsfiddle.net/eu4hde65/

Comment: Looks like a bug - reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4160

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue-

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4160

Meanwhile set alpha and beta to 0 and set stacking to false will solve the problem.

It still be 3d - but with no angle and not stack.

This code work for me-

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            margin: 75,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 0,
                beta: 0,

            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                depth: 40,
                stacking: false,
                grouping: false,
                groupZPadding: 0,
                dataLabels:{
                enabled:true,
                format:'<span style="color:{point.color};"> {point.y:.0f}</span>'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4],
            stack: 1
        }, {
            data: [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2],
            stack: 1
        }, {
            data: [7, 9, 8, 7, 5, 8],
            stack: 2
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this??? 
this is nice solution...

Here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/4dccq/481/)!

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        margin: 75,
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 35,
            beta: 15,
            depth: 110
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            depth: 40,
            stacking: true,
            grouping: false,
            groupZPadding: 10,
            dataLabels:{enabled:true}
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        stack: 0
    }, {
        data: [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2],
        stack: 1
    }, {
        data: [7, 9, 8, 7, 5, 8],
        stack: 2
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: This is not an answer - this should be a comment. If you are using `column` type chart, then all series are of that type by default. Next in `plotOptions` you are setting options for `bar` - they will not be applied for `column` type series. The problem in `column` type series: http://jsfiddle.net/4dccq/482/